# IOS SWIFT Как отправить запрос с таким JSON body и content-type через Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift

В Postman выставляю content-type = "application/json" а в body/raw пишу следующий json.

```
{
  "coordinates": [0,0],
  "range": [0,1],
  "options": { }
}
```

Все работает, приходит корректный ответ. 
Вопрос, как реализовать тоже самое на Swift через Alamofire request?

Написав и запустив следующее:

```
 let parametrs: Parameters = [
        "coordinates": [0,0],
        "range": [0,1],
        "options" : [:]
    ]
    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
        ]
    request(ServerManager.apiUrl, method: .post , parameters: parametrs, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
    }
```

Я получаю ошибку: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам приходит некорректный формат JSON.
Попробуйте так написать `.responseString`. Представить полученный данные как строку. Далее проверить полученные данные на корректность формата JSON.

```
request(ServerManager.apiUrl, method: .post , parameters: parametrs, headers: headers).responseString { response in
        print(response)
    }
```

UPD:

Добавьте `encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody` в реквест.

Comment: Выводится как я понимаю кастомный ответ сервера "Something broke". И на него видимо и вылетает ошибка. Тогда по идее я отправляю неправильный json, не такой как указано у меня в Postman. В чем может быть ошибка? Может этот словарь нужно как-то преобразовать?

Comment: А если вывести response.debugDescription, то content-type = text/html, так и должно быть?

Comment: Заметил  UPD после опубликования своего ответа) Спасибо за помощь!